# Htaccess Rewrite Rule for Sub-Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup a rewrite rule and I need it to apply to a large number of URL's. How can I set a wildcard so that if a directory starts with a certain word ( like 'how' or 'can') , the rewrite is applied?

This is what I have currently and it is not working

```
RewriteRule ^/can(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re in a .htaccess file, you need to remove the contextual path prefix from the pattern (in this case probably `/`):

```
RewriteRule ^can(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```